# php array: replacing parent key with child key

Tags: php, arrays

How in php to replace the key in an array, with the key of a sub-array to get this effect:
from:

```
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [for_a] => me
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [for_b] => you
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [for_c] => bleeh
        )
)`
```

to:

```
`Array
(
    [for_a] => me
    [for_b] => you
    [for_c] => bleeh

)`
```

I tried with array_column, but it had no effect

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do it like this:

This method assumes that there is only one element in each (the hardcoded `[0]`s in `$arr2[array_keys($arr)[0]] = array_values($arr)[0];`)

```php
<?php
//initialize source array
$arr1 = array(
    array("for_a"=>"me"),
    array("for_b"=>"you"),
    array("for_c"=>"bleeh")
);

//initialize output array
$arr2 = array();

//debug printsource array
print_r ($arr1);

foreach($arr1 as $arr){
    $arr2[array_keys($arr)[0]] = array_values($arr)[0];

}
//debug: print output array
print_r ($arr2);
```

It is not the most elegant way. There is a method called [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) where you can define a callback function parsing each element of your array, in which you can make sure you don't overwrite the existing elements of the array.

Comment: yes! this is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

@Josste gave a good example, and here's another way you *could* do it:

Looping through your array twice, once to grab the parent array and then again for each of the children then use the parent key to update a `new` array key for the output.

```
<?php
$array = [
    [
        'for_a' => 'me'
    ],
    [
        'for_b' => 'you'
    ],
    [
        'for_c' => 'bleeh'
    ]
];

$new = [];
foreach($array as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        $new[key($arr)] = $val;
    }
}

echo "<pre>" . print_r($new, TRUE) . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a functional-style version of James and Ronaldo's answers:

```php
$input = [
    [ "for_a" => "me" ],
    [ "for_b" => "you" ],
    [ "for_c" => "bleeh", "for_d" => "blerg" ]
];

$output = array_reduce($input, 'array_merge', []);

var_dump( $output );
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["for_a"]=>
  string(2) "me"
  ["for_b"]=>
  string(3) "you"
  ["for_c"]=>
  string(5) "bleeh"
  ["for_d"]=>
  string(5) "blerg"
}
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

**Edit:** Actually, all you need is `array_merge()` and argument unpacking:

```php
$output = array_merge(...$input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this php script:

```
<?php

$vetor[] = array("for_a" => "me");
$vetor[] = array("for_b" => "you");
$vetor[] = array("for_c" => "bleeh");

print_r($vetor);

foreach($vetor as $x)
{
    foreach($x as $key=>$value) {
        $vetor2[$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($vetor2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest one-liner would be,

```
$output = array_merge(...$input); // Merge every node to 1 level.
```

You can read all about **...(splat operator)** [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php).
[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ahUBH)